# Query hung or way too long?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.4, java

As part of the proccess of new items added to our system, some tables and relations are created programmaticaly via trigger, but it seems to be failing quite often right now. The DDL seems to be either taking too long or, definitely hung.

What other info would be relevant to provide for further analysis?

PostgreSQL version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

Problematic SQL sentence & associated Java Stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
  Where: SQL statement "CREATE TABLE reports.avl_historico_354676056031379(
  CONSTRAINT reports_pk_historico_354676056031379_fecha_imei PRIMARY KEY (fecha, imei),
  CONSTRAINT reports_avl_historico_only_354676056031379 CHECK (imei = 354676056031379),
  CONSTRAINT reports_fk_avl_historico_354676056031379_imei FOREIGN KEY (imei) REFERENCES public.avl_equipo (imei) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
INHERITS (reports.avl_historico)
WITHOUT OIDS;"
PL/pgSQL function reports.trigger_crea_historico_imei() line 3 at EXECUTE statement
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
        at waypoint.soporte.equipos.CreateEquipo.doPost(CreateEquipo.java:105)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:822)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.rollback(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:839)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.rollback(Unknown Source)
        at waypoint.soporte.equipos.CreateEquipo.doPost(CreateEquipo.java:266)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Related Structures:

**Table AVL_EQUIPO**

```
CREATE TABLE avl_equipo
(
  avl_equipo_clase integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  descripcion character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  imei bigint NOT NULL,
  serie character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  codigo character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  marca character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  modelo character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  panic_button integer DEFAULT 0,
  activado integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  fecha_activacion timestamp without time zone,
  box character varying(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'oem'::character varying,
  prioridad integer DEFAULT 0,
  conexion character varying(10) DEFAULT 'BATERIA'::character varying,
  sensor_ignicion boolean DEFAULT true,
  ingreso timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  id serial NOT NULL,
  traspaso integer DEFAULT 0,
  traspaso_fecha timestamp without time zone,
  horometro_activo integer DEFAULT 0,
  gsm character varying(8) DEFAULT 'MOVISTAR'::character varying,
  actualizar integer DEFAULT 0,
  odometro_gps boolean DEFAULT false,
  adc_activo integer DEFAULT 0,
  enable_power boolean DEFAULT false,
  enable_bateria boolean DEFAULT false,
  marca_id integer DEFAULT 0,
  modelo_id integer DEFAULT 0,
  toolkit integer DEFAULT 0,
  propietario integer DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT pk_avl_equipo PRIMARY KEY (imei),
  CONSTRAINT unique_avl_equipo_serie UNIQUE (serie)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE avl_equipo
  OWNER TO waypoint;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypoint;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointtx;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointtomcat;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointphp;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointsoporte;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointsalesforce;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointadminuser;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointagenda;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointmachines;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO waypointreports;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE avl_equipo TO readonly;

-- Index: index_equipo_clase

-- DROP INDEX index_equipo_clase;

CREATE INDEX index_equipo_clase
  ON avl_equipo
  USING btree
  (avl_equipo_clase);

-- Index: index_equipo_imei

-- DROP INDEX index_equipo_imei;

CREATE INDEX index_equipo_imei
  ON avl_equipo
  USING btree
  (imei);


-- Trigger: llama_trigger_crea_historico_imei on avl_equipo

-- DROP TRIGGER llama_trigger_crea_historico_imei ON avl_equipo;

CREATE TRIGGER llama_trigger_crea_historico_imei
  AFTER INSERT
  ON avl_equipo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE reports.trigger_crea_historico_imei();

-- Trigger: triggerNuevoInstantaneo on avl_equipo

-- DROP TRIGGER "triggerNuevoInstantaneo" ON avl_equipo;

CREATE TRIGGER "triggerNuevoInstantaneo"
  AFTER INSERT
  ON avl_equipo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE inicializar_instantaneo();
```

**Table AVL_HISTORICO**

```
CREATE TABLE reports.avl_historico
(
  fecha timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  latitud double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  longitud double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  altitud double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  velocidad double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  cog double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  nsat integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  tipo character(1),
  utc_hora time without time zone,
  fix_fecha date,
  imei bigint NOT NULL,
  registro timestamp with time zone,
  input1 integer DEFAULT 0,
  input2 integer DEFAULT 0,
  input3 integer DEFAULT 0,
  input4 integer DEFAULT 0,
  hdop double precision,
  adc double precision DEFAULT (-99),
  ignicion integer DEFAULT 1,
  adc2 double precision,
  power integer,
  driverid integer,
  ibutton2 integer,
  ibutton3 integer,
  ibutton4 integer,
  trailerid integer,
  adc3 double precision,
  adc4 double precision,
  horometro bigint,
  odometro bigint,
  panico integer DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT reports_pk_avl_historico PRIMARY KEY (fecha, imei)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE reports.avl_historico
  OWNER TO waypointsoporte;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO waypointsoporte;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO waypointtx;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO waypointtomcat;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO waypoint;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO waypointadminuser;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE reports.avl_historico TO readonly;

-- Index: reports.index_reports_avl_historico_fecha_imei_nsat_hdop

-- DROP INDEX reports.index_reports_avl_historico_fecha_imei_nsat_hdop;

CREATE INDEX index_reports_avl_historico_fecha_imei_nsat_hdop
  ON reports.avl_historico
  USING btree
  (fecha, imei, nsat, hdop);
```

**Sidenote: Yesterday we discovered that omiting the FK CONSTRAINT with avl_equipo actually solves the problems, but unfortunately that's not a supported solution.**

Comment: Run it in the psql client first - see what the error is there. **ALWAYS** a good idea to debug SQL through the client (rather than Java/whatever).

Comment: Give us your structures avl_equipo and avl_historico.

Comment: @Vérace added what you requested and a sidenote that allows to avoid the problem, but that's not a valid soluton